# WinAPI in C# book

Tags: c#, winapi, unmanaged

Im looking for a "book" which teach you winapi in C#, something like

- the basics of win32 programming and winapi.
- teaching you how to use unmanaged code in C#.
- call win32 functions from .net to other running application:

stuff like moving windows , reading text from richedit and texts, accessing listview32, click buttons, resizing windows, etc.

I`m not sure if a book like this exists but i think it would be great if we had one.

Comment: Why would you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look no further than this - it is a timeless classic:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/

It will teach you about WIN API, and using the API from the c# code - you'll be able to find tons of resources on the net.  Like:

http://pinvoke.net/

Comment: Petzold of-course is an amazing book, but i was wondering if we can get a book which have most of concepts of Petzold book but in C#, 

i tried to use Pinvoke Add-in for vs but i guess it doesnt work for 2010

Comment: also i guess that Petzold book is kinda out-dated.

Comment: Petzold is not out of date at all. You need to understand the basics and they haven't changed much since Windows 1.0.

Comment: @David - I would say exactly that, but it's better to have it coming from someone else :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you won't find that kind of book. What you need is:

1. WinAPI book
2. C# book
3. COM/Interop book

Comment: I would argue you don't even need the C# book provided they already had a decent knowlege of C#.

Answer (score 0):

C++/CLI in action http://www.manning.com/sivakumar/